# Css background image not getting set

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to set the background image using

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "theurltothebackground";
```

but it keeps giving me an error saying

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
> at (index):11
> (anonymous) @ (index):11

and I have checked and double-checked the code and I am very confused as to why it is giving me that error. Please help me

Answer:
Thanks to [isherwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1264804/isherwood),
I had the script before the body element

Comment: That error does seem odd if there is a body element present when the script runs. Is there? Please share more information about your script and its location in the document.

Comment: Could you please share or edit the question with the code surrounding that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [background**I**mage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp) and "url('url')"

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('image.png')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [backgroundImage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp)

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "theurltothebackground";
```